# kw_only and slots dataclass compatibility with older versions of Python

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

How can I make use of the new `kw_only` and `slots` features available in Python 3.10's [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) while also supporting older version of Python?

The main reason I want to set `kw_only` is so that I can have more confidence values go to the right field, and `slots` is for an object I'm likely creating lots of and don't want an unnecessary `dict` floating around behind the scenes.

I initially thought to use something like:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

# check if we're using Python >= 3.10
if 'kw_only' in dataclass.__kwdefaults__:
  _dataclass = dataclass

  # redefine this to ignore new options
  def dataclass(cls, *, kw_only=False, slots=False, **kwargs):
    if cls is None:
      return _dataclass(*kwargs)
    return _dataclass(cls)
```

but this caused MyPy to complain about the function being redefined.

Python 3.8 is the oldest version I care about supporting personally.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this by using:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

# kw_only and slots were only introduced in Python 3.10
KW_ONLY_DATACLASS = dict(kw_only=True) if 'kw_only' in dataclass.__kwdefaults__ else {}
SLOTS_DATACLASS = dict(slots=True) if 'slots' in dataclass.__kwdefaults__ else {}

# set kw_only=True on Python 3.10, ignoring if not supported
@dataclass(**KW_ONLY_DATACLASS)
class Foo:
    foo: int

# and demo setting slots along with frozen
@dataclass(frozen=True, **SLOTS_DATACLASS)
class Bar:
    bar: int
```

the idea is to define a set of dictionaries that can be expanded and will fill out the appropriate parameters.

I'm looking in `dataclass.__kwdefaults__` to check which parameters are supported by the current Python interpreter.  It also seems possible to use `dataclass.__code__.co_varnames` but didn't because this requires looking another level deeper.